# Unity Raycast2D problem when the character sitting on the corner

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Hi I have a problem with the Raycast2D. When the character sitting on the platform like on the image, the Raycast2D dosen't work. I have tried the Raycast and RaycastAll both. How can I detect the platform under the character when he's on the corner?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aF71.jpg

```
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        RaycastHit2D[] hit = Physics2D.RaycastAll(transform.position, -Vector2.up, 2f, layerMask);
        if(hit[0].collider != null)
        {
            Destroy(hit[0].collider.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put a trigger on the feet of the character and if its colliding with the platform, hes on it.

Comment: Instead of using single raycast at the center of the player, use two raycast on left and right end of the player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1) Use multiple raycasts

In your code, the game only detects a platform if the center of your player is standing above it. To detect the platform at all times, you should use two raycasts at the bounds of your character's collider.

```
void Update()
{
    // Cast the rays
    castRays(transform.localScale.x / 2f);
}

private void castRays(float distanceFromCenter)
{
    // Return if the ray on the left hit something
    if(castRay(new Vector2(-distanceFromCenter, 0f) == true) { return; }
    // Return if the ray on the right hit something
    else if(castRay(new Vector2(distanceFromCenter, 0f) == true) { return; }
}


private bool castRay(Vector2 offset)
{
    RaycastHit2D hit; // Stores the result of the raycast

    // Cast the ray and store the result in hit
    hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + offset, -Vector2.up, 2f, layerMask);

    // If the ray hit a collider...
    if(hit.collider != null)
    {
        // Destroy it
        Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);

        // Return true      
        return true;
    }

    // Else, return false
    return false;
}
```

*Optional: You can re-include the ray in the center in case there are platforms smaller than the player or for safety.*

### 2) Use a trigger

Place a `BoxCollider2D` at the feet of the character and set 'isTrigger' to true. When it enters another collider it will call "OnTriggerEnter2D".

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
}
```